# why am i having memory leaks when applying ngModel inside ngFor loop?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

so in my angular 5 app i have the following code :

```
<div *ngFor='let part of (post.student | async).get("qcm")'>
       <mat-checkbox>this can't be checked in or checked out</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

`post.student` is of type PromiseObservable.

`post.student | async` is of type DocumentSnapshot (a Firestore document).

`(post.student | async).get("qcm")` is an array of three objects.

my problem is :

1) the checkbox is not working (can't be checked in or out)

2) if i try to apply the ngModel directive on the checkbox like so:

```
<div *ngFor='let part of (post.student | async).get("qcm")'>
       <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]='myBool'>this can't be checked in or checked out</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

then the whole site blocks, using task manager i can see that my site have memory leaks now :

[task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKyDQ.png)

please note that if i use another array of objects other than `(post.student | async).get("qcm")` everything works fine.

also there are no errors in the console.

i have no idea what's going on, any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: ngModel is being used to bind properties between the view and controller.
Since you do not have any properties for the checkbox - do not add ngModel. If you cannot check/uncheck the checkbox - view errors in your console. Probably there is some JavaScript error

Comment: @checkmate I can't write a complete answer about this, but maybe your component is retrieving too much information. Accordly to the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe): "When the component gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid potential memory leaks." When the component gets destroyed...

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't add comments, I just try to post some info that might help you here as an answer. 
I don't think you can just add ngModel like that. You have to bind it to an object, like `[(ngModel)]="myDataModel"`. Note that the `[] and ()` are there so there is a two way binding, meaning whatever is in you myDataModel object, will be reflected at the checkbox any time. (So basically - so if you change the model, the cehckbox will change and if you cahnge the checkox the model will change). You dont have to always add two way binding, check the angular site for more information about this. 
Also, the checkbox thingy might be a js thingy, check your browser console for errors. I assume some error happened and it interrupted the running of the js code. 
I hope it somewhat helps finding your problem.

Comment: the same thing goes for two way binding with [(ngModel)] i wrote ngModel alone before for simplicity sake. i've edited the post now.